# How can I have a correct decimal format with a PHP namespace function?

Tags: php

I am working on my program to include name spaces, and I have been having some issues with decimal points. The number I am trying to achieve is $11,698.58 for a Future Value application that I am working on. But the application is printing out this number: 11698.5856. Did i do a little mess up on the code? I just need another pair of eyes to help me out on this one. Thanks!

functions.php

```
<?php

namespace fuller\math{
function future_value($investment, $years, $interest_rate, $future_value_f, $compoundMonthly = FALSE){
    // calculate the future value
$future_value = $investment;
$future_value_f = '$' . number_format($future_value, 2);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $years; $i++) {
    $future_value = ($future_value + ($future_value * $interest_rate * .01));    
}
if (isset($compoundMonthly)) {
    $compoundMonthly = 'Yes';
} else {
    $compoundMonthly = 'No';
}

return $future_value;
}

function currency_format($investment_f, $investment, $future_value, $future_value_f){

    // apply currency  formatting
$investment_f = '$' . number_format($investment, 2);
$future_value_f = '$' . number_format($future_value, 2);
return $investment_f;
}

// apply percent formatting
function percent_format($interest_rate_f, $interest_rate, $yearly_rate_f){
$interest_rate_f = number_format($interest_rate, 2) . '%';
$yearly_rate_f = $interest_rate . '%';
return $yearly_rate_f;
}
}
```

Comment: you should format only after all calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just format the `$future_value` after calculating growth:

```
$years=2;
$interest_rate=4;
$future_value=11698.58;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $years; $i++) {
    $future_value = ($future_value + ($future_value * $interest_rate * .01));    
}
echo $future_value;
$future_value_f = '$' . number_format($future_value, 2);
echo "<br>$future_value_f";
return $future_value_f;  // you weren't returning the formatted value
```